# Gnuplot: How to "stretch" multiple files along the 3rd dimension in splot?

Tags: gnuplot, fence-plots

I want to compare nine data sets in gnuplot using `splots`. Each of the files is in a subdirectory and corresponds to a different parameter. I have a `list` of file names, so something like `plot for [file in list] file u 1:5` works well. However, I want to be able to make a fence plot out of that by somehow strechting these files out along a third axis in `splot`.

How do I do something like `splot for [file in list] file u 1:5:<LIST OF VALUES>`, where the `<LIST OF VALUES>` is the list of parameters that doesn't appear in the data files themselves, but has to be put in by hand? The explicit list is {0.25,0.5,1,5,10,15,20,25,30}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could loop over an integer index and extract the corresponding file name and z-index from a string variable:

```
#as a minimal example, plot the value of the "z-index"
#and use the file name as key label

fileList="file1.dat file2.dat"
valsList="0.1 0.2"

plot for [i=1:words(fileList)] real(word(valsList, i)) t word(fileList, i)
```

In newer versions of Gnuplot, this can be simplified with arrays.

Comment: Hm, doesn't work for what I want to do: `splot for [i=1:words(filelist)] word(filelist,i) u 1:5:real(word(valslist,i))` leads to
        `internal error : non-STRING argument`

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec - could you try with `u 1:5:(real(word(valslist, i)))`? Without the extra pair of parentheses, `real(word(valslist, i))` is interpreted as column number...

Comment: I had tried that, but my mistake was somewhere else: I delimited the values in `valslist` with *commas* instead of *spaces*. Now it works like a charm, many thanks!